# Show $ x^2 = 1 + y^2 + z^2$ has infinitely many solutions

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Show $ x^2 = 1 + y^2 + z^2$ has infinitely many solutions

Can anyone give me the specific steps for this problem?

Comment: [See this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for info on how to write math on this site.

Comment: are x,y,z integers?

Comment: Start with $x=2k+1$ is an odd number, then follow with $k$ is a square, then see what happens...

Comment: @ShubhamUgare Yes they are all ints

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Choose any even number to be $y$. Then $1+y^2$ is odd and is therefore the difference between two successive squares.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**
Let $y=2k, z=2k^2$ and then complete the square on right hand side.

Answer (score 2):

Any number that is not of the form $4k+2$ is represented by the quadratic form $x^2-z^2$. So we just have to prove that for an infinite number of $y$, $y^2+1\not\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, but that holds for any even $y$.